# IOS Stream freezing when not connecting swift 3

Tags: ios, stream, swift3

below is the code I have.

It works perfectly when the IP of the server is correct, but in a case where the ip is not correct, the app freezes once it tries to send the message, and if that is commented out, then again when it tries to receive.

I need to put in place something to inform the user that the IP is incorrect, and not freeze the app.

I have tried a switch case, I have tried checking .hasBytesAvailable and .hasSpaceAvailable, which both return false regardless, as well as a few other suggestions on the net. If anybody can offer some help that would be great.

Oh just an FYI this is all in Swift 3

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation

    class SocketTest{
      var output: NSString?
      func SocketWorks(test: String) -> NSString{
      output = "Hello"
      let CDIP = CoreDataUDP()
      let serverIP = CDIP.getIP()
      var server = serverIP
      var port = 5000
      //var host :NSHost = NSHost(address: server)
      var inp :InputStream?
      var out :OutputStream?
      Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: server, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
      let inputStream = inp!
      let outputStream = out!
      inputStream.open()
      defer {
          inputStream.close()
      }
      outputStream.open()
      defer {
          outputStream.close()
      }



        let messageSend: String = test
        let messageSendCount = messageSend.characters.count
        outputStream.write(messageSend, maxLength: messageSendCount)


        let bufferSize = 1024
        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

        let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
        if bytesRead >= 0 {
            output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        } else {
            NSLog("Its not right yet", output!)
        }


    print(output!)

    return output!

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use asynchronous communication by implementing stream`s delegate. See [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html) (Apple docs) for details.